# How to Refresh a Datagrid after performing a search in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need a button code to refresh the datagrid so that it will show the full list after i perform a search in vb2010 application. For example, If my list has 100 customers, i search for Obama and get 5 results, how will i get back to my 100 customers full list?

```
Tbx2.Text = DataGridView1.RowCount()

If Cbx1.Text = "Adm. No." Then
    Me.StudentsBindingSource.Filter = "AdmissionNumber = '" & Tbx1.Text & "'"
ElseIf Cbx1.Text = "Name" Then
    Me.StudentsBindingSource.Filter = "FullName Like '%" & Tbx1.Text & "%'"
ElseIf Cbx1.Text = "Class/Stream" Then
    Me.StudentsBindingSource.Filter = "Class_Stream Like '%" & Tbx1.Text & "%'"
ElseIf Cbx1.Text = "County" Then
    Me.StudentsBindingSource.Filter = "County = '" & Tbx1.Text & "'"
End If` This is my search code and its working fine
```

Comment: Can put your code odf search ?

Comment: how do you initially populate your list? Is it from a datatable?

Comment: from a datatable in sqlserver though a dataset.

Comment: Did you try `Me.StudentsBindingSource.RemoveFilter()` or `Me.StudentsBindingSource.Filter = nothing` ?

Comment: Me.StudentsBindingSource.RemoveFilter() has worked.

Comment: @HenryGathigira I-ve posted it as an answer. Can you accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Me.StudentsBindingSource.RemoveFilter()` to set the Filter to nothing and display all the rows.